# Book an appointment via a bot - which cards/attachments?

Tags: botframework

I'd like my bot to take the user through the process of booking an appointment. I want almost exactly the flow show on the home page of the https://dev.botframework.com/

[image]

However I cannot seem to find the right attachment types to represent the list of buttons or the follow up details with the 'Book now' button. Can anyone tell me which types of attachment/card these are?

Answer (score 0):

List of buttons:

It doesn't look like FB Messenger. On Telegram, a `HeroCard` without an image would look this way (separate messages). Otherwise a `SigninCard` may do.

Bottom card:

```
ThumbnailCard card = new ThumbnailCard() {
    //...
};

activity.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() {
     ThumbnailCard.ToAttachment()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know I could omit the picture from a hero card - will try and report back